# How do I link (opus) external/third party codec with pjsip for ios

Tags: ios, codec, pjsip

I am making an app for ios which uses **pjsip** library , but I want to use  **opus as the codec.**
I have not been able to find any source which explains how to do it. Can anyone please help.

Could someone tell both the steps involved in compiling opus codec and then using it with pjsip.

Also, if possible, could someone give a link for **libopus.a** which has been **compiled for i386 architecture**. I believe that it may work if I can get hold of this library.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to just copy with what [csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) has already done.  Altho csipsimple is android based, the opus (or any codec) integration will work on any platform that you can compile the codec for.  For opus you can compile it for pretty much any platform that you would like.

OPUS actually provides features that pjsip has no API for.  So the current integration can't fully use the opus codec.  Even with this non-optimal integration I have found that opus works really well in pjsip.